# gobuster fills screen with html code and blanks

Tags: linux, http, webserver, penetration-tools

learning CTF games, I made gobuster from git.

Using it by

./gobuster dir -u http://10.10.19.14:3333 -w ~/HTools/lists/gobuster_big.txt

brings following output:

```
===============================================================
Gobuster v3.1.0
by OJ Reeves (@TheColonial) & Christian Mehlmauer (@firefart)
===============================================================
[+] Url:                     http://10.10.19.14:3333
[+] Method:                  GET
[+] Threads:                 10
[+] Wordlist:                /home/jens/HTools/lists/gobuster_big.txt
[+] Negative Status codes:   404
[+] User Agent:              gobuster/3.1.0
[+] Timeout:                 10s
===============================================================
2020/11/20 13:52:49 Starting gobuster in directory enumeration mode
===============================================================
```

And then starts a lot of rubbish. Tons of blanks or eol. And within paragraphs of

```
/<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/236661?s=400&amp;v=4" /><meta name="twitter:site" content="@github" /><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" /><meta name="twitter:title" content="digination/dirbuster-ng" /><meta name="twitter:description" content="dirbuster-ng is C CLI implementation of the Java dirbuster tool - digination/dirbuster-ng" /> (Status: 400) [Size: 301]
/<meta property="og:image" content="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/236661?s=400&amp;v=4" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="GitHub" /><meta property="og:type" content="object" /><meta property="og:title" content="digination/dirbuster-ng" /><meta property="og:url" content="https://github.com/digination/dirbuster-ng" /><meta property="og:description" content="dirbuster-ng is C CLI implementation of the Java dirbuster tool - digination/dirbuster-ng" /> (Status: 400) [Size: 301]
/<meta name="optimizely-datafile" content="{&quot;version&quot;: &quot;4&quot;, &quot;rollouts&quot;: [], &quot;typedAudiences&quot;: [], &quot;anonymizeIP&quot;: true, &quot;projectId&quot;: &quot;16737760170&quot;, &quot;variables&quot;: [], &quot;featureFlags&quot;: [], &quot;experiments&quot;: [{&quot;status&quot;: &quot;Running&quot;, &quot;audienceIds&quot;: [], &quot;variations&quot;: [{&quot;variables&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18630402174&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;}, {&quot;variables&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18866331456&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;control&quot;}], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18651193356&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;_features_redesign_rollout&quot;, &quot;layerId&quot;: &quot;18645992876&quot;, &quot;trafficAllocation&quot;: [{&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;18630402174&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 500}, {&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;18866331456&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 1000}, {&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;18630402174&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 5000}, {&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;18630402174&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 5500}, {&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;18866331456&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 10000}], &quot;forcedVariations&quot;: {&quot;143327983.1601483920&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;, &quot;1955030087.1562868941&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;, &quot;1983887325.1550021416&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;, &quot;1947530619.1600461583&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;}}, {&quot;status&quot;: &quot;Running&quot;, &quot;audienceIds&quot;: [], &quot;variations&quot;: [{&quot;variables&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19157301901&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;}, {&quot;variables&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19115494094&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;control&quot;}], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19139621248&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;signup_prompt_launchpad&quot;, &quot;layerId&quot;: &quot;19159450734&quot;, &quot;trafficAllocation&quot;: [{&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;19115494094&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 5000}, {&quot;entityId&quot;: &quot;19157301901&quot;, &quot;endOfRange&quot;: 10000}], &quot;forcedVariations&quot;: {&quot;262350301.1605284875&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;, &quot;550830608.1557172966&quot;: &quot;launchpad&quot;}}], &quot;audiences&quot;: [{&quot;conditions&quot;: &quot;[\&quot;or\&quot;, {\&quot;match\&quot;: \&quot;exact\&quot;, \&quot;name\&quot;: \&quot;$opt_dummy_attribute\&quot;, \&quot;type\&quot;: \&quot;custom_attribute\&quot;, \&quot;value\&quot;: \&quot;$opt_dummy_value\&quot;}]&quot;, &quot;id&quot;: &quot;$opt_dummy_audience&quot;, &quot;name&quot;: &quot;Optimizely-Generated Audience for Backwards Compatibility&quot;}], &quot;groups&quot;: [], &quot;attributes&quot;: [{&quot;id&quot;: &quot;16822470375&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;user_id&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;: &quot;17143601254&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;spammy&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;: &quot;18175660309&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;organization_plan&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;: &quot;18813001570&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;is_logged_in&quot;}, {&quot;id&quot;: &quot;19073851829&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;geo&quot;}], &quot;botFiltering&quot;: false, &quot;accountId&quot;: &quot;16737760170&quot;, &quot;events&quot;: [{&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;17911811441&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;hydro_click.dashboard.teacher_toolbox_cta&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18124116703&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;submit.organizations.complete_sign_up&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18145892387&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;no_metric.tracked_outside_of_optimizely&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18178755568&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.org_onboarding_checklist.add_repo&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18180553241&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;submit.repository_imports.create&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18186103728&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.help.learn_more_about_repository_creation&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18188530140&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;test_event.do_not_use_in_production&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18191963644&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.empty_org_repo_cta.transfer_repository&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18195612788&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.empty_org_repo_cta.import_repository&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18210945499&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.org_onboarding_checklist.invite_members&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18211063248&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.empty_org_repo_cta.create_repository&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18215721889&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.org_onboarding_checklist.update_profile&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18224360785&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.org_onboarding_checklist.dismiss&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18234832286&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;submit.organization_activation.complete&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18252392383&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;submit.org_repository.create&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18257551537&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;submit.org_member_invitation.create&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18259522260&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;submit.organization_profile.update&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18564603625&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;view.classroom_select_organization&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18568612016&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.classroom_sign_in_click&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18572592540&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;view.classroom_name&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18574203855&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.classroom_create_organization&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18582053415&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.classroom_select_organization&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18589463420&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.classroom_create_classroom&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18591323364&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.classroom_create_first_classroom&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18591652321&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.classroom_grant_access&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18607131425&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;view.classroom_creation&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;18831680583&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;upgrade_account_plan&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [&quot;19139621248&quot;], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19064064515&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.signup&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19075373687&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.view_account_billing_page&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [&quot;19139621248&quot;], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19077355841&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.dismiss_signup_prompt&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19079713938&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.contact_sales&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19120963070&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.compare_account_plans&quot;}, {&quot;experimentIds&quot;: [], &quot;id&quot;: &quot;19151690317&quot;, &quot;key&quot;: &quot;click.upgrade_account_cta&quot;}], &quot;revision&quot;: &quot;319&quot;}" /> (Status: 414) [Size: 323]
[ERROR] 2020/11/20 13:52:49 [!] parse http://10.10.19.14:3333/<span style="background-color: #79b8ff;width: 0%;" class="Progress-item progress-pjax-loader-bar "></span>: invalid URL escape "%;\""
Progress: 149 / 17906 (0.83%)
```

or

```
/<svg height="32" class="octicon octicon-mark-github text-white" viewBox="0 0 16 16" version="1.1" width="32" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8c0 3.54 2.29 6.53 5.47 7.59.4.07.55-.17.55-.38 0-.19-.01-.82-.01-1.49-2.01.37-2.53-.49-2.69-.94-.09-.23-.48-.94-.82-1.13-.28-.15-.68-.52-.01-.53.63-.01 1.08.58 1.23.82.72 1.21 1.87.87 2.33.66.07-.52.28-.87.51-1.07-1.78-.2-3.64-.89-3.64-3.95 0-.87.31-1.59.82-2.15-.08-.2-.36-1.02.08-2.12 0 0 .67-.21 2.2.82.64-.18 1.32-.27 2-.27.68 0 1.36.09 2 .27 1.53-1.04 2.2-.82 2.2-.82.44 1.1.16 1.92.08 2.12.51.56.82 1.27.82 2.15 0 3.07-1.87 3.75-3.65 3.95.29.25.54.73.54 1.48 0 1.07-.01 1.93-.01 2.2 0 .21.15.46.55.38A8.013 8.013 0 0016 8c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8z"></path></svg> (Status: 403) [Size: 1132]
```

I tried quiet mode. No help.
Using Ubuntu 20.04.

Why is that? Thx

Answer (score 1):

Your wordlist file might have the wrong format.

It should contain only a list of dir names written in column because gobuster does the parsing of the specified file line-by-line, inserts the entire line content to the URI and makes a request.
For example your worldlist file should look like this:

```
PDF
PRUEBA
PRUEBAS
Pages
People
Press
Privacy
PrivacyPolicy
Products
Projects
Prova
Provas
Pruebas
Publications
```

It seems that when you did the download of this file you've saved it with the entire HTML markup.